# Use @PreAuthorize with token authentication

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have spring boot based application which exposes REST APIs. These APIs are consumed by Web Portal. While invoking API, JWT token is passed which is used by an AuthInterceptor. This interceptor validates token. AuthInterceptor is configured via "WebMvcConfigurerAdapter"

Now I want to use @PreAuthorize for endpoints to check Permissions. But when I added below class "MethodSecurityConfig" to use @PreAuthorize, I am getting below message while staring application.

```
Using generated security password: 9816a6b7-46aa-4c60-ae7e-4959a19d8e30

This generated password is for development use only. Your security configuration must be updated before running your application in production.
prompt for user name and password.
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter { 
}
```

Then while invoking API @PreAuthorize gets skipped as its not aware of authentication.
Is there way to tell @PreAuthorize to use token-based authentication in AuthInterceptor?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your security configuration, did you indicate the paths to secure on HttpSecurity object? Something like http..authorizeRequests()..antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()

Comment: No we didn't specified any paths to secure.

Comment: What I understood for spring security is that you have to tell the paths to secure or not and then have a chain for secured endpoints where you have filters, the authentication manager, the authentication provider that uses a UserDetailsService to retrieve the user data (with the rights = list of GrantedAuthority). After that the security context should be initialized and then it is used when you tell that an endpoint should be secured by roles (with @PreAuthorize).

Comment: So first I think you have to tell to spring security what endpoints should be secured, configure everything in the chain to check the token and retrieve user rights to initialize the security context and after that you should be able to secure your endpoint with @PreAuthorize. I am trying to do the configuration of spring security to manage a JWT token too with the last version of spring boot (2.7.4) but I have some questions too here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74028061/common-spring-security-configuration-for-multiple-apps)

Comment: Also the @EnableWebSecurity annotation seems to be missing

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. @EnableWebSecurity is used. I will try your suggestions. I am also looking for end to end sample for filter, authentication manager and security context.